# D3 Alternate Calendar - Coloring by Bin

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Alternate D3 Calendar as we see [here](http://bl.ocks.org/KathyZ/c2d4694c953419e0509b) uses the values of the columns Open and Close to calculate the colors for the calendar. I am trying to modify the code to color the calendar based on threshold/binning of the column "Open". Modified code below divides the csv file in to buckets of 10. I am stuck as my code doesn't work(calendar does not color and the tooltip displays "2008-01-01:undefined") anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var width = 960,
        height = 750,
        cellSize = 25; // cell size

    var no_months_in_a_row = Math.floor(width / (cellSize * 7 + 50));
    var shift_up = cellSize * 3;

    var day = d3.time.format("%w"), // day of the week
        day_of_month = d3.time.format("%e"),// day of the month
        day_of_year = d3.time.format("%j"),
        week = d3.time.format("%U"), // week number of the year
        month = d3.time.format("%m"), // month number
        year = d3.time.format("%Y"),
        percent = d3.format(".1%"),
        format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

    var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([1,10])
   // .range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));
   .range(["#5E4FA2", "#3288BD", "#66C2A5", "#ABDDA4", "#E6F598","#FFFFBF", "#FEE08B", "#FDAE61", "#F46D43", "#D53E4F"]);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
        .data(d3.range(2008, 2011))
      .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
      .append("g");

    var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) { 
          return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
        })
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "day")
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          var month_padding = 1.2 * cellSize*7 * ((month(d)-1) % (no_months_in_a_row));
          return day(d) * cellSize + month_padding; 
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) { 
          var week_diff = week(d) - week(new Date(year(d), month(d)-1, 1) );
          var row_level = Math.ceil(month(d) / (no_months_in_a_row));
          return (week_diff*cellSize) + row_level*cellSize*8 - cellSize/2 - shift_up;
        })
        .datum(format);

    var month_titles = svg.selectAll(".month-title")  // Jan, Feb, Mar and the whatnot
          .data(function(d) { 
            return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("text")
          .text(monthTitle)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            var month_padding = 1.2 * cellSize*7* ((month(d)-1) % (no_months_in_a_row));
            return month_padding;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            var week_diff = week(d) - week(new Date(year(d), month(d)-1, 1) );
            var row_level = Math.ceil(month(d) / (no_months_in_a_row));
            return (week_diff*cellSize) + row_level*cellSize*8 - cellSize - shift_up;
          })
          .attr("class", "month-title")
          .attr("d", monthTitle);

    var year_titles = svg.selectAll(".year-title")  // Jan, Feb, Mar and the whatnot
          .data(function(d) { 
            return d3.time.years(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("text")
          .text(yearTitle)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) { return width/2 - 100; })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) { return cellSize*5.5 - shift_up; })
          .attr("class", "year-title")
          .attr("d", yearTitle);


    //  Tooltip Object
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
      .append("div").attr("id", "tooltip")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "10")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .text("a simple tooltip");

    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devsar/d3talk/master/dji.csv", function(error, csv) {
    
    /*--- start of my code --- */
    var mvalues=[];
    //reading all the metric values into an array
    for (i=0;i<csv.length;i++){
      mvalues.push(Number(csv[i].Open));
    }
     var histGenerator=d3.layout.histogram()
                .range([d3.min(mvalues),d3.max(mvalues)])
                .bins(10);


    var bins = histGenerator(mvalues);

      //Assigning a value to the group column(created in this loop only) determining which bucket the row falls for example : Row 1 Metric Value may fall in bucket 6
      for (j=0;j<bins.length;j++)
        {

          for  (i=0;i<csv.length;i++)
            {
          if(((Number(csv[i].Open)> bins[j].x) && (Number(csv[i].Open)<=bins[j].x+bins[j].dx)))
            {
              csv[i].Group = j;

            }

            }
        }
        
       
        var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return d[0].Group; })
        .map(csv);
        // debugger;        

        
     /*--- end of my code --- */ 
  
  
        /*var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
        .map(csv);
    */
      rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
        .select("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + data[d]; });

      //  Tooltip
      rect.on("mouseover", mouseover);
      rect.on("mouseout", mouseout);
      function mouseover(d) {
        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      //  var percent_data = (data[d] !== undefined) ? percent(data[d]) : percent(0);
           var percent_data = (data[d] !== undefined) ? data[d] : 0;  //modified above line of code to display only Open value
      
        var purchase_text = d + ": " + percent_data;

        tooltip.transition()        
                    .duration(200)      
                    .style("opacity", .9);      
        tooltip.html(purchase_text)  
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+30 + "px")     
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px"); 
      }
      function mouseout (d) {
        tooltip.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0); 
        var $tooltip = $("#tooltip");
        $tooltip.empty();
      }

    });

    function dayTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toString().split(" ")[2];
    }
    function monthTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
    }
    function yearTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toString().split(" ")[3];
    }
```

```css
body {
        font: 1.1em sans-serif;
      }

      #chart{
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .background {
        fill: #eee;
      }

      line {
        stroke: #fff;
      }

      text.active {
        fill: red;
      }

      .day {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: #ccc;
      }

      .month {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }
      .year-title {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }

      /* color ranges */
      .RdYlGn .q0-11{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
      .RdYlGn .q1-11{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
      .RdYlGn .q2-11{fill:rgb(244,109,67)}
      .RdYlGn .q3-11{fill:rgb(253,174,97)}
      .RdYlGn .q4-11{fill:rgb(254,224,139)}
      .RdYlGn .q5-11{fill:rgb(255,255,191)}
      .RdYlGn .q6-11{fill:rgb(217,239,139)}
      .RdYlGn .q7-11{fill:rgb(166,217,106)}
      .RdYlGn .q8-11{fill:rgb(102,189,99)}
      .RdYlGn .q9-11{fill:rgb(26,152,80)}
      .RdYlGn .q10-11{fill:rgb(0,104,55)}

      /* hover info */
      #tooltip {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: First make the exmaple run: how do you think that including d3v3 and d3v4 makes it all easier. They have very different API's. Just setup the correct scale you want for your Open binning and call this scale when you assign the color to a rect.

Comment: I modified the code to reflect d3.v3 library.

Comment: No more errors but the screen is still blank.

Comment: When i try to debug i get this error "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header." I am not sure why this would come up in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

- don't use `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` for numeric min max, read the docs
- set a class equal to the bin number and use a CSS style to color because there is already a CSS style for uncolored rects
- don't use the color hex as a CSS class

You have to fix the tooltips yourself because it uses jQuery and that was not included in the sample.

Put the div for the charts in the html.

```js
var width = 960,
        height = 750,
        cellSize = 25; // cell size

    var no_months_in_a_row = Math.floor(width / (cellSize * 7 + 50));
    var shift_up = cellSize * 3;

    var day = d3.time.format("%w"), // day of the week
        day_of_month = d3.time.format("%e"),// day of the month
        day_of_year = d3.time.format("%j"),
        week = d3.time.format("%U"), // week number of the year
        month = d3.time.format("%m"), // month number
        year = d3.time.format("%Y"),
        percent = d3.format(".1%"),
        format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

    var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([1,10])
   // .range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));
   .range(["#5E4FA2", "#3288BD", "#66C2A5", "#ABDDA4", "#E6F598","#FFFFBF", "#FEE08B", "#FDAE61", "#F46D43", "#D53E4F"]);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
        .data(d3.range(2008, 2011))
      .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
      .append("g");

    var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) { 
          return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
        })
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "day")
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          var month_padding = 1.2 * cellSize*7 * ((month(d)-1) % (no_months_in_a_row));
          return day(d) * cellSize + month_padding; 
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) { 
          var week_diff = week(d) - week(new Date(year(d), month(d)-1, 1) );
          var row_level = Math.ceil(month(d) / (no_months_in_a_row));
          return (week_diff*cellSize) + row_level*cellSize*8 - cellSize/2 - shift_up;
        })
        .datum(format);

    var month_titles = svg.selectAll(".month-title")  // Jan, Feb, Mar and the whatnot
          .data(function(d) { 
            return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("text")
          .text(monthTitle)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            var month_padding = 1.2 * cellSize*7* ((month(d)-1) % (no_months_in_a_row));
            return month_padding;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            var week_diff = week(d) - week(new Date(year(d), month(d)-1, 1) );
            var row_level = Math.ceil(month(d) / (no_months_in_a_row));
            return (week_diff*cellSize) + row_level*cellSize*8 - cellSize - shift_up;
          })
          .attr("class", "month-title")
          .attr("d", monthTitle);

    var year_titles = svg.selectAll(".year-title")  // Jan, Feb, Mar and the whatnot
          .data(function(d) { 
            return d3.time.years(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("text")
          .text(yearTitle)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) { return width/2 - 100; })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) { return cellSize*5.5 - shift_up; })
          .attr("class", "year-title")
          .attr("d", yearTitle);


    //  Tooltip Object
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
      .append("div").attr("id", "tooltip")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "10")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .text("a simple tooltip");

    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devsar/d3talk/master/dji.csv", function(error, csv) {
    
    /*--- start of my code --- */
    var mvalues=[];
    //reading all the metric values into an array
    for (i=0;i<csv.length;i++){
      csv[i].Open = Number(csv[i].Open);
      mvalues.push(csv[i].Open);
    }
     var histGenerator=d3.layout.histogram()
                .range([d3.min(mvalues), d3.max(mvalues)])
                .bins(10);


    var bins = histGenerator(mvalues);

      //Assigning a value to the group column(created in this loop only) determining which bucket the row falls for example : Row 1 Metric Value may fall in bucket 6
      for (j=0;j<bins.length;j++)
        {

          for  (i=0;i<csv.length;i++)
            {
          if(((csv[i].Open> bins[j].x) && (csv[i].Open<=bins[j].x+bins[j].dx)))
            {
              csv[i].Group = j;

            }

            }
        }
        
        
        var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return d[0].Group; })
        .map(csv);
        
     /*--- end of my code --- */ 
  
  
        /*var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
        .map(csv);
    */
      rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
          .attr("class", function(d) { return `day q${data[d]}-11`; })
          //.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(data[d]); })
        .select("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + data[d]; });

      //  Tooltip
      //rect.on("mouseover", mouseover);
      //rect.on("mouseout", mouseout);
      function mouseover(d) {
        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      //  var percent_data = (data[d] !== undefined) ? percent(data[d]) : percent(0);
           var percent_data = (data[d] !== undefined) ? data[d] : 0;  //modified above line of code to display only Open value
      
        var purchase_text = d + ": " + percent_data;

        tooltip.transition()        
                    .duration(200)      
                    .style("opacity", .9);      
        tooltip.html(purchase_text)  
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+30 + "px")     
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px"); 
      }
      function mouseout (d) {
        tooltip.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0); 
        var $tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
        $tooltip.empty();
      }

    });

    function dayTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toString().split(" ")[2];
    }
    function monthTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
    }
    function yearTitle (t0) {
      return t0.toString().split(" ")[3];
    }
```

```css
body {
        font: 1.1em sans-serif;
      }

      #chart{
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .background {
        fill: #eee;
      }

      line {
        stroke: #fff;
      }

      text.active {
        fill: red;
      }

      .day {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: #ccc;
      }

      .month {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }
      .year-title {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }

      /* color ranges */
      .RdYlGn .q0-11{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
      .RdYlGn .q1-11{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
      .RdYlGn .q2-11{fill:rgb(244,109,67)}
      .RdYlGn .q3-11{fill:rgb(253,174,97)}
      .RdYlGn .q4-11{fill:rgb(254,224,139)}
      .RdYlGn .q5-11{fill:rgb(255,255,191)}
      .RdYlGn .q6-11{fill:rgb(217,239,139)}
      .RdYlGn .q7-11{fill:rgb(166,217,106)}
      .RdYlGn .q8-11{fill:rgb(102,189,99)}
      .RdYlGn .q9-11{fill:rgb(26,152,80)}
      .RdYlGn .q10-11{fill:rgb(0,104,55)}

      /* hover info */
      #tooltip {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**Edit**

Now you have converted the `Open` column to `Number` and then `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` give the correct result. I have modified the example accordingly.

Comment: What does this line of code do in rect.filter ? 
          .attr("class", function(d) { return `day q${data[d]}-11`; })
as my application is NOT accepting the return parameter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals a way to eliminate all those string concatenations. What JS engine do you use? Modern browsers should be able to handle it.

Comment: Internet explorer is ONLY debugging tool it allows

Comment: I use Chrome. You can rewrite is as a string `+` operation.